# Unable to INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE from another query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I am working on the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cons` (
  `Id` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `Client_ID` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `voice_cons` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `data_cons` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to get some data from another table, `cdr`, which contains a row per event. This means every call or data connection has its own row.

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+-------+
| Client_ID | Data_Up_Link | Data_Down_Link | Price |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+-------+
|         1 |           23 |             56 |     0 |
|         1 |           12 |              3 |     0 |
|         1 |            0 |              0 |     5 |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+-------+
```

I need to compute the total voice and data consumption for each `Client_ID` in my new `cons` table, but just keeping a single record for each `Client_ID` and `day`. To keep the question simple, I will consider just one day.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| Client_ID | data_cons | voice_cons |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|         1 |        94 |          5 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I have unsuccessfully tried the following, among many other (alias, .

```
insert into cons_day (Id, Client_ID, voice_cons, MSISDN, day)   
select 
concat(Client_ID,date_format(date,'%Y%m%d')), 
Client_ID, 
sum(Price) as voice_cons, 
date as day 
from cdr
where Type_Cdr='VOICE' 
group by Client_ID;

insert into cons_day (Id, Client_ID, data_cons, MSISDN, day)   
select 
    concat(Client_ID,date_format(date,'%Y%m%d')), 
    Client_ID, 
    sum(Data_Down_Link+Data_Up_Link) as data_cons, 
    Calling_Number as MSISDN, 
    date as day 
from cdr
where Type_Cdr='DATA' 
group by Client_ID
on duplicate key update data_cons=data_cons;
```

But I keep getting the values unchanged or receiving SQL errors. I would really appreciate a piece of advice.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get `64` for `data_cons` with `sum(Data_Down_Link+Data_Up_Link)`? Shouldn't it be `94`? Also it looks like you need `data_cons`  and `voice_cons` per day. Is this correct?

Comment: @peterm Sorry, typo. You are correct, I need a row per Client_ID and day. I tried to keep the question as simple as possible, but I overdid that. I'll edit right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it seems that `Id` column in `cons` table is absolutely redundant. You already have `ClientID` and `Day` columns. Just make them `PRIMARY KEY`.

That being said the proposed table schema might look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cons` 
(
  `Client_ID` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `voice_cons` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `data_cons` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Client_ID`, `day`)
);
```

Now you can use conditional aggregation to get your `voice_cons` and `data_cons` in one go

```sql
SELECT Client_ID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type_CDR = 'VOICE' THEN price END) voice_cons,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type_CDR = 'DATA'  THEN Data_Up_Link + Data_Down_Link END) data_cons,
       DATE(date) day
  FROM cdr
 GROUP BY Client_ID, DATE(date)
```

Note: you **have to** `GROUP BY` both by `Client_ID` and `DATE(date)`

Now the `INSERT` statement should look like

```sql
INSERT INTO cons (Client_ID, voice_cons, data_cons, day)
SELECT Client_ID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type_CDR = 'VOICE' THEN price END) voice_cons,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type_CDR = 'DATA'  THEN Data_Up_Link + Data_Down_Link END) data_cons,
       DATE(date) day
  FROM cdr
 GROUP BY Client_ID, DATE(date)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE voice_cons = VALUES(voice_cons), 
                        data_cons  = VALUES(data_cons);
```

Note: since now you simultaneously get both `voice_cons` and `data_cons` you might not need `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause at all if you don't process data for the same dates multiple times.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66d72/1)** demo

Comment: Your answer is amazing. Not only you solved my particular problem, but also made me improve my understanding of SQL and reduce my code in about an 80%. Thank you very much, peterm!

Comment: @Serge You're quite welcome. I'm glad I could help. Good luck :)